# What SQL Server Compact data type should I use for money vals and for a "fake double" val?

Tags: sql-server-ce, double, type-conversion, sqldatatypes, currency

I have the following columns: Qty, Cost, Margin, ListPricec, DeptDotSubdept that I need to create in a SQL Server Compact database table. Qty seems like it should be an int, but you can actually have, say 1.5 of this or that, so it needs to not be an int. The next three (Cost, Margin, and ListPrice) are monetary vals. The last one is a "fake" double which combines a department number and a subdepartment number to be a single entity; e.g., dept 42, subdepartment 99 are stored as "42.99"

What SQL Server Compact data types are best for these types? There is no "money" or "currency" type, dagnab it. In the corresponding C# class, all of these class members are doubles.

Comment: Why would you store dept and subdepartment in the same column? If it's two INTs, then store two INTs. You can always use a computed column or a view to expose it as a concatenation, but storing it that way from the start seems unwise.

Comment: I agree with Aaron but if you really must, why not a varchar for ``DeptDotSubdept``?

Comment: You're right; I was too focused on copying the existing schema; instead, I'll change double DeptDotSubdept, int Subdept to
int Dept, int Subdept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to use a datatype of FLOAT. I'm not having any luck finding a link to data type documentation for SqlCE right now. <s>I'll update if I find something.</s>

Update:
[SqlCE 4.0 DataTypes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx)

NUMERIC is probably your best choice.

Comment: Why FLOAT and not NUMERIC? Float has issues with rounding and approximation, and should only be used in very specific scenarios where its limitations are fully understood.

Comment: Yes, very true, thank you. I found the documentation that I was looking for on data types and updated my answer. I had remembered using FLOAT in the past for a specific use case, forgot that CE does have the NUMERIC type.